# Android - how to send String from Alertdialog to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I'm using `AlertDialog` with 1 `EditText`. I want to know how i can send String from `AlertDialog` to `Fragment`.

Please check my code below.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_datasource){
        enterdatasourceId();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The code for enterdatasourceId is:

```
 public void enterdatasourceId() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cutom_dialog,null);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Enter you unique ID");
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText datasource1 = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.datasource_id);

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            String dsource = datasource1.getText().toString().trim();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("Datasource",dsource);
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog customDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    customDialog.show();
}
```

The following is the code of the fragment where i want to receive that String

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Datasource = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("Datasource");
}
```

In `Fragment` i want to receive the String that i entered in `AlertDialog` and from here i'm sending that String as a parameter in my other class. I want to make it clear that the `Activity` where i'm using `AlertDialog` is dashboad2.java and the fragment where i want to receive that String is within the same `Activity` (dashboard2.java)

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.putExtra("Datasource",dsource);
This intent is used for go to other activity?

Comment: No! When app starts an alertdialog with edittext is popup and on pressing Ok button the dialog disappears and fragment get focused

Comment: You can use like this : 
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);

Comment: and in fragment what should i do to get the data

Comment: would you please share some code

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();          
bundle.putString("abc","abc");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);  


You can get that data like this : 
String abc=getArguments().getString("abc");

Comment: to use fragment.setArguments(bundle) should i create fragment object where i want to send data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Comment: it is not working i'm getting null pointer exception

Comment: Can you post the log?

Comment: 07-11 15:15:40.619 13115-13115/com.example.zohai.healthapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.zohai.healthapp, PID: 13115
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: You can use static variable also to get the values of the string

Comment: how? kindly share

Comment: static String abc = "abc";

Here you can get this value like 
Classname.abc;

Comment: Not working anyother solution?

Comment: SharedPreference

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DialogFragment.
Create an interface in the dialogFragment.
Implement the interface in your parent fragment.

Here is the sample how you can continue.

```
public class YourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    OnSubmitListener mListener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_layout);
         dialog.show();

         Button proceed = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.proceedBtn);
         Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
         EditText datasource1 = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.datasource_id);

    proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          mListener.GetDataSource(datasource1.getText().toString().trim());
         } 
         dismiss();
        }
    });

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
         return dialog;
    }



public interface OnSubmitListener {
                void GetDataSource(String dataSrc);
            }
}
```

Implement YourDialogFragment.OnSubmitListener in your fragment. It will make you override GetDataSource(String) method, where you will get the string.

```
if (id == R.id.action_datasource){
     //        enterdatasourceId();
     YourDialogFragment fragment = new YourDialogFragment ();
     fragment.mListener = getActivity();
     fragment.show((Activity) context).getFragmentManager(), "dialogFragment"); 
     return true;
}
```

Comment: But how i can get the string from edittext in dialog fragmnet and pass it to other fragmnet

Comment: You are using interface for that.

**mListener.GetDataSource(datasource1.getText().toString().trim());**

when you press the proceed button in dialogfragment, you will get the string in the edittext on Overridden method in the parent fragment

Comment: and in other fragment how i will get the passed string

Comment: please share some code how i will get the passed string in other fragment

Comment: Implement **YourDialogFragment.OnSubmitListener**, it will  force you to override the method **GetDataSource(String dataSrc)** ..

This string **dataSrc** will be the value of your edittext in the dialogFragment.

Comment: would you please share some detail code of other fragment where i will override the method please

Comment: "how to send String from Alertdialog to **Fragment** "

implement on the same Fragment

Comment: Yes i want to send the string from alert dialog to myfragment

Comment: make it like: public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements YourDialogFragment.OnSubmitListener. I hope you already have your myFragment class, so just implement YourDialogFragment.OnSubmitListener interface

Comment: i'm using your code. i'm getting error on dismiss();

Comment: i have solved that error but now i'm getting error in this code

Comment: if (id == R.id.action_datasource){
                YourDialogFragment fragment = new YourDialogFragment ();
                fragment.mListener = getActivity();
                fragment.show((Activity) context).getFragmentManager(), "dialogFragment");
                return true;
            }

Comment: i put this code in mainactivity where there is options menu. error is mListener is not public